# How to overlay a county boundary on a raster file?

Tags: raster, r, overlay

I want to overlay California county boundary top of raster layer.

Here is is my code:

```
data(coastsCoarse)
data(countriesLow)
library(gtools)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(sp)

# Raster file
RAD2012 <- raster(paste(getwd(), "/2012bil/2012ASC5min_ppt_spas1306_0001_20121222_0005_UTC.asc.bil", sep = ""))

list.ras <- mixedsort(list.files(paste(getwd(), "/2012bil/", sep = ""), full.names = T, pattern = ".asc.bil")) 

# stack raster file
RAD2012.all <- stack(list.ras)

# png file tile(time stamp)
list.files <- mixedsort(list.files(paste(getwd(), "/2012bil/", sep = ""), full.names = F, pattern = ".asc.bil")) 

outlist <- substr(list.files, 31, 43)

# plotting part
# I am using countriesLow
# I want to improve base layer from countriesLow to county boundary
```

[image]

```
for(i in seq(from=0, to=length(list.ras)-1, by=1)){
      png(paste(outlist[[i+1]],".png",sep=""))
    par(mfrow=c(1,1),oma=c(2,2,2,2))
    for(j in 1:1){
          plot(RAD2012.all[[i+j]])
              plot(countriesLow, add = T)
              #plot(countriesHigh, add = T)
              title(outlist[[i+j]])
    }
      dev.off()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of what you can do with `rasterVis` and `sp` packages. You will have to adapt to your own use.

```
library(rasterVis)
library(sp)

# Download States boundaries (might take time)
out <- getData('GADM', country='United States', level=1)

# Extract California state
California <- out[out$NAME_1 %in% 'California',]

# Plot raster and California:
levelplot(RAD2012.all) + 
layer(sp.polygons(California))
```